# Is there any way to map action on struts2 namespace root?

Tags: struts2

I have a namespace in struts.xml

```
<package name="mobile" namespace="/mobile" extends="mainApp">
    <action name="abc" class="x.y.Abc"
        method="abc">
        <result name="input">/blank.html</result>
            <result name="success">/blank.html</result>
        </action>
</package>
```

I want to map `localhost/myApp/mobile/` with the action `abc`

I don't mind `localhost/myApp/mobile/*` getting mapped with the action `abc`

is there any way to meet this requirement?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35312643/573032

Comment: @RomanC Sir I did not understand the explanation. Please post some snippet, it could be more useful because I am not a native English person. post it in answer section so that I can mark it as answer.

Comment: Can you explain in English the requirement?

Comment: In a plain simple words, I want to fire an action on localhost:8080/appname/namespace/ i.e. namespace slash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to fire an action on localhost:8080/appname/namespace/ i.e. namespace slash

After slash should be action name and if it's empty you should configure empty action name.

```
<package name="mobile" namespace="/mobile" extends="mainApp">
    <action name="" class="x.y.Abc"
        method="abc">
        <result name="input">/blank.html</result>
            <result name="success">/blank.html</result>
        </action>
</package>
```

Answer (score 0):

try `<default-action-ref/>`:

```
<package name="mobile" namespace="/mobile" extends="mainApp">

<default-action-ref name="abc"/> <!-- I added this -->

    <action name="abc" class="x.y.Abc"
        method="abc">
        <result name="input">/blank.html</result>
            <result name="success">/blank.html</result>
        </action>
</package>
```